# Setting up a domain specific email with Bluehost and AWS

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bluehost

Currently, I am using bluehost as my domain registrar. I then I have some custom nameservers to point the domain to an amazon ec2 instance.

However, I would like to set up an email address to send and receive email. For sending emails (marketing and transaction) I have registered with mailjet so I have some type of record thing (MX record maybe) that I set up with AWS to point to the mailjet servers.

But now, I would like to get a personal email, robert@mysite.com, that I can put on my business card. Before, when I was using bluehost to do my hosting, I could just set it up with bluehost and then use POP or IMAP or whatever through gmail to access all my emails. But now, when I try to set up an email via bluehost, I am unable to get POP or IMAP set up, and it doesn't receive emails when I check it through bluehost's default webmail client.

Has anyone dealt with this issue before?

I am hoping I can get an email set up through bluehost, because that seems to be the easiest. I tried to set up a mail server on my amazon instance once but I never figured it out and from what I read it wasn't worth it anyway. And mailjet doesn't offer any type of incoming email support.

Answer (score 1):

In order to receive emails on the domain that you set up with Bluehost, you need to change the MX record to point the Bluehost SMTP servers.

Currently you have it set to have all mail sent to robert@mysite.com sent over to Mailjet's Parse API ([see their documentation for Parse API](http://dev.mailjet.com/guides/parse-api-guide/)).

Bluehost support will be able to tell you the DNS changes that you need to make to receive and send emails, or you can take a look at [this Knowledge Base article](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/294) they have.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Bluehost MX management tool; for the current version, it doesn't work. Instead, use the cPanel to set the MX.